# Text log viewer with columns, filters and multi-line support

Tags: windows, logs, log-analysis

The tool should:

1. Be able to recognize columns: date/time, level, logger name, message (I use log4net format, also custom columns are desirable). Message column may be multi-line. Multi-line entries should be showed as a single row.
2. Be able to filter per-column (e.g. only from logger "NHibernate.SQL").
3. Be able to select and copy from filtered entries.
4. Be able to filter already filtered list (nested filtering).
5. Support inverted (exclusion) filtering (e.g. hide logger "NHibernate.SQL", exclusion with regexp is ok too).
6. Desirable: be able to save/load "favorite" filters with all nesting.
7. Be able to search and highlight results (in both full and filtered rows list, inside specific columns).

Price <= $100 (for indie).

Log example:

```
2016-07-01 13:59:51,928 [10] DEBUG MasterServer [(null)] - [u8917] Request BuyItemUpgrade, parameters = <Byte,Object> (2) { 1 = 330225, 3 = True }
2016-07-01 13:59:51,944 [10] DEBUG MasterServer [(null)] - [u8917] Request BuyItemUpgrade, parameters = <Byte,Object> (2) { 1 = 330225, 3 = True }
2016-07-01 13:59:51,944 [10] DEBUG MasterServer [(null)] - [u8917] Request BuyItemUpgrade, parameters = <Byte,Object> (2) { 1 = 330225, 3 = True }
2016-07-01 13:59:51,944 [11] DEBUG NHibernate.SQL [(null)] - SELECT ... [some query here]
    at NHibernate.AdoNet.Util.SqlStatementLogger.LogCommand(String message, IDbCommand command, FormatStyle style) in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\AdoNet\Util\SqlStatementLogger.cs:line 56
   at NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteReader(IDbCommand cmd) in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\AdoNet\AbstractBatcher.cs:line 216
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.GetResultSet(IDbCommand st, Boolean autoDiscoverTypes, Boolean callable, RowSelection selection, ISessionImplementor session) in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Loader\Loader.cs:line 1200
   at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.DoQuery(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, Boolean returnProxies) in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Loader\Loader.cs:line 419

2016-07-01 13:59:51,944 [22] DEBUG NHibernate.SQL [(null)] - INSERT INTO ... [another SQL]
    at NHibernate.AdoNet.Util.SqlStatementLogger.LogCommand(String message, IDbCommand command, FormatStyle style) in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\AdoNet\Util\SqlStatementLogger.cs:line 56
   at NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteReader(IDbCommand cmd) in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\AdoNet\AbstractBatcher.cs:line 216
   at NHibernate.Id.IdentityGenerator.InsertSelectDelegate.ExecuteAndExtract(IDbCommand insert, ISessionImplementor session) in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Id\IdentityGenerator.cs:line 74
   at NHibernate.Id.Insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.PerformInsert(SqlCommandInfo insertSQL, ISessionImplementor session, IBinder binder) in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Id\Insert\AbstractReturningDelegate.cs:line 42
   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Insert(Object[] fields, Object obj, ISessionImplementor session) in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Persister\Entity\AbstractEntityPersister.cs:line 3035
   at NHibernate.Action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.Execute() in p:\nhibernate-core\src\NHibernate\Action\EntityIdentityInsertAction.cs:line 75
```